Add Collsion property with XML file
I am trying to use the arm.xml in mujoco to pick and place object, the arm is going through the table , it should have collision property. I am not sure why it's doing so I already tried adding  condim="4" contype="1", even then it's happening
    <body name="fl_link1" pos="0.233 0.3 0.8212">
  <inertial pos="0.00609525 -0.00429682 0.017959" quat="0.680193 0.680193 -0.193229 0.193229"
    mass="0.0608351" diaginertia="8.61803e-05 6.38197e-05 3e-05" />
  <joint name="fl_joint1" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 0 1" limited="true" range="-10 10" damping="0" />
  <geom type="mesh" group="1" density="2.83" rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1" mesh="link1" 
    friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
  
  <body name="fl_link2" pos="0.02 0 0.0402">
    <inertial pos="-0.132382 0.00220381 0.00011179" quat="0 0.706195 0 0.708017" mass="1.07333"
      diaginertia="0.0160201 0.01596 0.000499897" />
    <joint name="fl_joint2" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0" limited="true" range="-10 10" damping="100" />
    <geom type="mesh" group="1" density="2.83" rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1" mesh="link2" 
      friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
    
    <body name="fl_link3" pos="-0.264 0 0" quat="-3.67321e-06 -1 0 0">
      <inertial pos="0.187203 -0.000305676 -0.0514833"
        quat="0.269626 0.618013 0.251786 0.694238" mass="0.499405"
        diaginertia="0.00388848 0.00385541 0.000286113" />
      <joint name="fl_joint3" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0" limited="true" range="-10 10"
        damping="20" />
      <geom type="mesh" group="1" density="2.83" rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1"
        mesh="link3" friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
      
      <body name="fl_link4" pos="0.245 0 -0.056">
        <inertial pos="0.0388885 0.00295169 -0.0353283"
          quat="0.913916 -0.0752199 0.315785 -0.243679" mass="0.0809713"
          diaginertia="0.000184798 0.000152076 5.31251e-05" />
        <joint name="fl_joint4" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0" limited="true" range="-10 10"
          damping="5" />
        <geom type="mesh" density="2.83" rgba="0.898039 0.917647 0.929412 1" mesh="link4"
          friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
        
        <body name="fl_link5" pos="0.06575 -0.001 -0.0825">
          <inertial pos="0.00289957 3.15827e-05 0.0526189" quat="0.998829 0 -0.0483866 0"
            mass="0.602357" diaginertia="0.000724856 0.00069 0.000205144" />
          <joint name="fl_joint5" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 0 1" limited="true" range="-10 10"
            damping="2" />
          <geom type="mesh" density="2.83" rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1" mesh="link5"
            friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
          
          <body name="fl_link6" pos="0.02845 0 0.0825" quat="-3.67321e-06 -1 0 0">
            <geom type="mesh" pos="0.04181 0.01149 0.07402" euler="0 1.919 1.57" density="2.83"
              rgba="0.898039 0.917647 0.929412 1" mesh="dabai" 
              friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
            <camera name="fl_dabai" pos="0.0494 0 0.07134" euler="0 -1.221 -1.57" fovy="55" />
            <inertial pos="0.0471798 0.00010297 -0.000138511"
              quat="0.495436 0.504523 -0.504523 0.495436" mass="0.462245"
              diaginertia="0.000910182 0.00068 0.000359818" />
            <joint name="fl_joint6" pos="0 0 0" axis="1 0 0" limited="true" range="-10 10"
              damping="0.1" />
            <geom type="mesh" density="2.83" rgba="0.898039 0.917647 0.929412 1" mesh="link6"
              friction="1 0.1 0.1" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
            
            <body name="fl_link7" pos="0.073574 0.024629 0">
              <inertial pos="-0.000327643 -0.00482005 -0.00167541" quat="0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5"
                mass="0.0484017" diaginertia="2e-05 2e-05 1e-05" />
              <joint name="fl_joint7" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0" type="slide" limited="true"
                range="0 0.04765" damping="100" />
              <geom type="mesh" density="1.1" friction="1 0.1 0.1"
                rgba="0.898039 0.917647 0.929412 1" mesh="link7" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
            </body>
            
            <body name="fl_link8" pos="0.073574 -0.024629 0">
              <inertial pos="-0.000327644 0.00482005 0.000752973" quat="0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5"
                mass="0.0484017" diaginertia="2e-05 2e-05 1e-05" />
              <joint name="fl_joint8" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 -1 0" type="slide" limited="true"
                range="0 0.04765" damping="100" />
              <geom type="mesh" density="1.1" friction="1 0.1 0.1"
                rgba="0.898039 0.917647 0.929412 1" mesh="link8" solimp="0.95 0.95 0.01" solref="0.01 1" condim="4" contype="1" conaffinity="1" />
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
      </body>
    </body>
  </body>

